# how to display the records from gridview which is latest record show on first row

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview

I have small application which uses a gridview. In that, when we insert the records into the database which is current that record show in first row of the gridview. Please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a primary key auto increment or an insert datetime in your table, you can query the database with a `ORDER BY ID DESC` or `ORDER BY INSERTDATE DESC` at the end of the select command.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use the BindingSource.Sort property. Enter the column name and "desc" if needed.

[MSDN documentation of Sort property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.BINDINGSOURCE.SORT%29;k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.BINDINGSOURCE%29;k%28VS.PROPERTIES%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)